# How to change the language of the TeXStudio?

Tags: languages, texstudio

I just can't figure out how to change the language of the IDE itself (not for the document)?

I am using TeXStudio (v.2.6.2).

Comment: Option->Configure TeXstudio->General->Language

Comment: Thanks, you should post this as an answer. I do not know how I've missed it, probably because of the `Default` value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find it in

```
Option->Configure TeXstudio->General->Language
```

[image: TeXstudio Configure]

Answer (score 2):

Just a Heads up, for mac OS: Top left conner: TeXstudio->preferences->General->languages

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find your favorite language under

> Option -> Configure TeXstudio -> General -> Language

you have to install the package

```
texstudio-l10n
```

for supporting more languages.