# Cannot find english in language option (TeX Studio)

Tags: texstudio

I installed TeX Live and TeX Studio on Windows 10. This TeX Studio language is not what I want, so I go to the option - configure - General - Language, but there is no english in language dropdown list. Some googling does not give me an answer. What should I do to set additional language that is not in language menu?

Actually, in the following link, someone said
"you have to install the package
texstudio-l10n."
([How to change the language of the TeXStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139599/how-to-change-the-language-of-the-texstudio))

But I cannot figure out how to install this on Windows 10 because everyone explain about this 'texstudio-l10n' with only for Linux on the internet I found, so I cannot even sure this is for Windows.

Comment: Is there an option `default` in the languages drop down menu? Usually is the last item in the list. Choose it. It gives you the English language?

Comment: @miltos I found it, it was at the upward direction.. I just scroll down hundreds of time what a shame

Comment: Perfect! Happy TeXing!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.